# feedparser removing <guid> and making long url as id - Python

Tags: python, rss

I am using [feedparser](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/common-rss-elements.html). I have a feed which has `<guid>` like this:

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">news_article_602262</guid>
```

and feed domain (dummy) is: `www.mydomain.com/feed/rss`

once i want to read this guid like

```
feed = feedparser.parse("www.mydomain.com/feed/rss")
print feed.entries[0].id
```

it is printing:

```
www.mydomain.com/feed/rss/news_article_602262
```

how can I get only `news_article_602262` ?

I know, i can further parse and stuff, but is there any shortcut for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.split(separator)`

```
>>> f = "www.mydomain.com/feed/rss/news_article_602262"
>>> f.split('/')[-1]
'news_article_602262'
```

In your case: `print feed.entries[0].id.split('/')[-1]`